# Unable to boot from ubuntu live USB duo to this error: ACPI Error AE_NOT_FOUND while resolving

Tags: boot, uefi, live-usb, ssd, acpi

I am trying to boot ubuntu from live usb to install it but keeps getting errors.
I tried multiple LTS versions 20.04, 22.04
The Laptop has ubuntu 20.04 with efi installed on the 1TB hdd but it is too slow
and Windows 11 installed on a partition in SSD
I want to install Ubuntu on a partition in the SSD but failed to boot the live USB
Any solution ?

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f5kr.jpg)

also I got different error when tried with Ubuntu 20.1
error: /casper/vmlinuz has invalid signature.
error: you need to load the kernel first.

Thanks

Comment: The ACPI error and the "initramfs failed to decode" errors I think are different errors.  Did you verify the ISO hash sum before writing it to the USB stick and booting to it?  initramfs failing to decode sounds more like the USB stick is not complete, and the ISO you used is not complete either.

Comment: No actually didn't do ISO hash sum, Can you please tell me how to do this ?
I tried multiple versions: 14.04, 16.04, 18.04, 20.04, 22.04 but old ones gave different errors and also failed to boot

Comment: 1. Any modern OS installed in a HDD will be slow. 2. If your hardware is new enough to support Windows 11 then only the latest Ubuntu release should be used. That means 22.04. Anything older than 20.04 is a waste of time, 18.04 has less than one year of support left and all the other ones you wasted you time with are out of support.

Comment: yeah, so I am trying to install latest ubuntu on  ssd partition and then remove the one installed on the HDD but faced this issue

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#2-necessary-software will be relevant.  How did you create the ISO in the first place, what utilities/tools did you use, and what OS did you use to create the USB stick with?

Comment: Yeah I checked the checksum of the iso, and it's OK. I created the Bootable USB using the startup disk creator on Ubuntu 20.04 that is installed on the HDD

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue in the sub stick, it seems to be corrupted, I bought a new one and it worked fine.

Thanks for your comments